# Winbind, what can cause corruption of cache?

Tags: winbind

I have a "working" Samba4 enviroment.
I use the old good method of Winbind, works fine but sometimes(after Samba upgrade version for example) the cache become "corrupt" and my user disappear.

```
wbinfo -i pinuser
failed to call wbcGetpwnam: WBC_ERR_DOMAIN_NOT_FOUND
Could not get info for user pinuser
```

If I delete the cache files the user magically appear

```
find /var/lib/samba/ /var/cache/samba/ -name gencache.tdb -exec rm -vf {} \;
systemctl restart winbind.service 
wbinfo -i pinuser
pinuser:*:10005:10016::/home/pinuser:/bin/bash
```

What can cause the cache corruption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution too easy.
After doing this command all works fine, without needing of delete any file, remain unsolved the reason of "corruption" of cache.

```
net cache flush
```

Let see the command "in action"

```
id pinuser
id: 'pinuser': no such user
sudo net cache flush
wbinfo -i pinuser
pinuser:*:10005:10016::/home/pinuser:/bin/bash
id pinuser
uid=10005(pinuser) gid=10016(domain users) groups=10016(domain users)
```